# Skipping battery level screen when powering on MacBook Pro with Touch ID button

Tags: startup, power

My MacBook Pro used to turn on automatically when I opened the lid. I didnt like that so I disabled that feature. Now I can manually turn on the macbook but it requires a couple button presses and a few tries. The intended method of turning it on now is via the touch id button. However when I press that it shows the battery level. I then have to press it again once or twice to get the machine to power on.

Is this the intended way to get the machine to power on with the touch id button, or is there some way I can skip the battery level screen to make the machine power up immediately? I tried log pressing the touch id button but that didnt seem to do it either.

---

Edit: I just did more testing. After I open the laptop, if I wait a few seconds (without pushing anything), the battery level appears by itself. If I wait for that to disappear, then push the touch id button, the laptop powers on. If however, I open the laptop and immediately press the touch id button (before the battery level has appeared), the battery level appears, but then nothing happens after the battery level disappears. I have to push the power button again after the battery level screen in order to power on the laptop.

Is there someway to skip that battery level screen so I can power on immediately?

Comment: It should turn on when you press it automatically

Comment: See update above